# Powering Arduino Relay Shield with Only Digital Pins

Tags: arduino

I was wondering if it would be possible to power a dual relay shield on just the Arduino's analog/digital pins. I know you are supposed to connect one to the ground and another to the 5V VCC port but all the ports are taken up by other components I cannot spare. I don't know if it will draw too much current, but if it won't short my Arduino I can send the positive signal, just a bit unsure of the grounding in the code.

Thank you

Comment: You'd rather risk burning out your Arduino instead of crimping together a few wires?

Comment: I don't want to burn out Arduino at all, but I really need all the VCC and GND ports. I have two IR sensors connected along with an RTC, and they all occupy all VCC ports. So what alternative might I have?

Comment: Crimping a few wires together.

Comment: On the digital pins or with the VCC/GND pins? I wouldn't object to crimping a few together I just want to make sure I keep the voltage and current safe.

Comment: "I just want to make sure I keep the voltage and current safe." crimping is safer than use your arduino for this

Comment: I understand crimping the the best option, but I don't understand how I should do it in this context. Should I have two cables connecting to the one VCc port on module or similar?